# Here Map Location pointer compass head?

Tags: android, google-maps, here-api

Here map followers does compass head can be applied to  map.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true); if yes please share me the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In theory you can change the image of the position indicator. But rotating the image is not supported, so you would need to replace the image permanently. 
All in all, I'd say it's much easier (and more flexible) to do this on your own.

Here's a full working example:

https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/CustomPositionMarker.zip

One comment: I use a LocalMapObject instead of MapMarker, so I can activate dynamic scaling and easy rotation.

Comment: MapLocalModel which library is this. Whr should I get this from?. Your work is admirable.

Comment: Included Here_SDK library, gson 2.24, jts- 1.14, jtsio-1.14 MapLocalModel is showing error how to reslove this?

Comment: what error is it showing ? Is my example working for you ? See documentation of the MapLocalModel here: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-maplocalmodel.html

Comment: @Marco Rotating the image of position indicator during navigation now supported or not??