# Here-SDK: How to show the default HereWeGo-Positionindicator?

Tags: android, here-api

How do i show the standard PositionIndicator from the HereWeGo-App in my MapActivity?

This one:

[image: this]

When i use this Code:

```
mPositioningManager = PositioningManager.getInstance()
mPositioningManager.addListener(
newWeakReference<PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener>(MyActivity.this));

if (mPositioningManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK_INDOOR))
{ 
   mapFragment.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);
}
```

i get this Indicator:

[image: This is what i get]

Is there some other way to create the "HereWeGo-Indicator"? As i know if you implement the Indicator iOS you get by default the "HereWeGo-Indicator".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use image than do like below

```
Image img_current_location = new Image();
img_current_location.setImageResource(R.drawable.custom_img);
```

after that set on PositionIndicator.

```
Map.getPositionIndicator().setMarker(img_current_location);
```

And if you dont want to use image at all than create compass header. sample example can downloaded from the below link.

https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/CustomPositionMarker.zip

some discussion can be found on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418698/here-map-location-pointer-compass-head/36423838#36423838).

It does not fit in your requirement but you can modify it.

Comment: I don't want my custom image. I know i can use any Image as Indicator. I want that same Indicator as in the HereWeGo-App and iOS if you use the Standard Indicator for implementation.

Comment: @elpatricko The position indicator used in the Here WeGo app is different than the default position indicator included with the HERE SDK. The app indicator is not available publicly.

Comment: It is in the iOS-SDK

Comment: This is not available on the Android SDK. The marker is HERE proprietary and I actually want to REMOVE it from iOS.